# emacs haskell-mode repl can't find hugs. how to use ghci instead?

Tags: haskell, emacs, cabal, ghci, hugs

To set up my haskell-in-emacs environment, I dutifully followed the instructions here:

http://tim.dysinger.net/posts/2014-02-18-haskell-with-emacs.html

When I load Main.hs, it syntax-highlights correctly.  When I do Ctrl-c Ctrl-l as instructed, it reports:

`Searching for program: No such file or directory, hugs.`

I'm pretty sure the problem is that it should be using ghci, but I'm new to these packages.

The contact page of the person that wrote the above page says that he does not want to be contacted.  So here we are.  Any help appreciated.

I'm on OS X 10.9.2 (Mavericks).  I already had emacs installed.  Otherwise I followed the instructions.

I'm grepping all the places that seem relevant but I can't find a direct mention of a hugs executable anywhere.

Does anyone know where this error message is coming from, and what I can do to get this working?

Comment: What does `haskell-program-name` seem to be set too?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Emacs/Inferior_Haskell_processes - you need to set `haskell-program-name` to ghci

Comment: @MikeHartl since your comment appears to answer the question, perhaps you should post it as an answer?